# JavaScript: How to add 'word-wrap' style to element

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you add the 'word-wrap' style to an element using JavaScript?

```
tables = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
    tables[i].style.word-wrap = 'break-word';
```

The above code produces the following error:

```
ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
```

Although the code works if I used a different style, ie...

```
tables[i].style.width = '300px';
```

'word-wrap' seems to be what I'm looking for though, as it works within a test CSS file and within HTML style tags.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `wordWrap` instead `word-wrap`

```
tables = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
    tables[i].style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
```

Style names in Javascript use camelCase. `-` is the arithmetic subtraction operator, it can't used in identifiers.

You could use bracket notation instead but it's not recommended

```
tables[i].style['word-wrap'] = 'break-word';
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript uses camel case for style property declarations

```
tables[i].style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
```

wordWrap is a object key, object keys must not include `-`.